# Redirect to homepage without changing address bar URL

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect people that enter the URL `domain.com/project/206/9` to `domain.com` but the URL `domain.com/project/206/9` should be displayed. Then I want to extract the numbers `206` and `9` from my URL and use that in my code.

I am using a Wordpress website.

Comment: try something you will surely get it

Comment: You need to add a rewriterule in your htaccess. Try it out, if it doesn't work, come back.

Comment: Have you tried the *search* feature? There are a lot of similar questions: [**CLICK**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=redirect+without+url+change) -- If your question is different, please show your attempts and state how it is different.

Comment: I used "RewriteRule ^project/(.*)$ motiongraphicscollective.com" to in my .htacces but this is not workin

Comment: I am stuck. Had tried several htaccess rewriterul's. I can redirect but also the url doesn't stay.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

Write below code in your htaccess file

```
Redirect domain.com/project/206/9 domain.com
```

It may help you.